# Java repaint not displaying component correctly

Tags: java, swing, components, panel, repaint

im developing an GUI Application, using JSWing, i load XML file, then deserialize it, then  i add all created object to the JPanel.
However, until i move the window, or click on the panel, this is how they looks like

[image]

After i move the window, they look correctly, so how to fix this issue <

I looked at this link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)
and it might be the answer, since in the constructor of the JComponent i use

```
setOpaque(true);
```

but im still not sure how to fix the issue since that part of documentation is very hard to understand (it somehow just does not make any sense to me :-D )

by the way, the painting itselfs goes something like this

```
for (NetObject o : objects) {

                addNewObject(o);
            }
```

and addNewObject (not whole code)

```
public void addNewObject(NetObject o) {



         DraggableComponent object = new DraggableComponent(o, editorIndex); //Creates a draggableComponent
        this.add(object);//Adds this component to main container

        object.setOverbearing(true); //On click ,this panel gains lowest z-buffer


            object.setSize(48, 48);
            object.setLocation(o.x - 23, o.y - 23);
            object.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.repaint(); //this = JPanel
```

}

and the overriden paintComponent code

```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (isOpaque()) {
            if (object.type == 2) { //tarnsition
                g.drawImage(transition, 0, 0, this);

            } else if (object.type == 1) {
                boolean test = g.drawImage(place, 0, 0, this); //place
                g.drawString(object.loadTokens(), 3, 27); // 1,2,3,4...
            }
        }

    }
```

i tried to call this.revalidate - after FOR EACH LOOP - didnt help, the only way that works is to move somehow with the window, strangely, this problem exists only @ Windows, my collegue is developing this exact same application under Linux, and he does not experience ani graphical issues.

I know that there been an awfully lot of topics like this, but i honestly was not able to figure out the solution.

Thanks for the answer,
OSiRiS

Comment: Maybe `pack()` will solve it.  Otherwise, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`setBackground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) API mentions that "It is up to the look and feel to honor this property, some may choose to ignore it." Set the graphics context's color explicitly in `paintComponent()` and invoke `fillRect()`.

Comment: See also the [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) property.

Comment: Thanks, simply g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 48, 48);
                boolean test = g.drawImage(config.place, 0, 0, this); //place
                g.drawString(object.loadTokens(), 3, 27); // 1,2,3,4... works !